# numpy slicing is really slow

Tags: python, numpy

I have a function where the core is as follows:

```
coord = 0
for y in range(sy, sy + 4):
    for x in range(sx, sx + 4):
        #cpc_x[coord] = spline_data[x, y, ..., 0]
        #cpc_y[coord] = spline_data[x, y, ..., 1]
        cpc_x[coord] = spline_data[x, y, 0, 0, 0]
        cpc_y[coord] = spline_data[x, y, 0, 0, 1]

        coord += 1
```

Now, if I use the syntax to access the array element as `spline_data[x, y, ..., 0]`. The code runs `6` times slower. Using it with the full indexing is much, much faster. I must say the function is called many times in a loop. So, I guess calculating the index is really slow but I was wondering if this is a known problem or if there is any way to work around this while still using this nice `...` syntax.

Comment: `...` is not the same as `0, 0`. It is `:, :`, which may be very very different. Since you don't provide nearly enough information to be able to say, I recommend that you update your question.

Comment: Um, `spline_data[x, y, ..., 0]` is not necessarily equivalent to `spline_data[x, y, 0,0, 0]` indeed, the former likely materializes much more

Comment: Ahhhhh...I was using it completely wrong then! Thanks for the helpful comments. 
@mods: Please close this question.